# SonarQube says "Covered by tests (3 of 4 conditions)" on a null check

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have a null check on a FileInputStream object and SonarQube says that on the first line of this block:

```
if (fileInputStream != null) {
    try {
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {}
}
```

only (and I quote): "Covered by tests (3 of 4 conditions)"

How in this world can there be 4 conditions? 
I can only see 2 conditions: either the object is null or not.
Can anyone post those other 2 conditions?
I use java 8.
Is there a way to please Sonar? A workaround? Anything.

Update: I removed the if statement and replaced the whole if block with

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileInputStream);
```

which checks for null and makes Sonar happy.

Comment: What is the coverage engine you use ? can you share a bit more context where this line of code appears ?

Comment: Thank you benzonico. I use maven, jacoco and sonarqube. The OS is Windows 10. I am not sure if I answered your question. Please let me know if you require additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Sonar 7.0 and Jacoco 6.5 it is now possible to use try with resources as a more elegant solution than

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileInputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder about the close() and finalized() methods?

Comment: From what I read elsewhere it may be that the compiler is adding some garbage there, maybe it adds conditions like: "is closed" or "is active" so in bytecode the if statement looks like: `if (object != null && !object.isClosed())`